# Handle all exceptions thrown, put them into flashMessage with ZF2

Tags: php, architecture, zend-framework2, standards

I need to catch properly, all my exceptions thrown in my ZF2 services and return the message into a flashMessage to the user.

This is what i tried in my Controller action:

```
try {
    $newConfigID = $this->configService->updateConfig($form->getData());
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->flashMessenger()->setNamespace('danger')->addMessage($e->getMessage());
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('config/update', array('idConfig' => $idConfig));
}
```

This is working like a charm, but i'm not sure if it's good to do this in Controller, if it's the better/clean way to achieve this. Maybe an event can handle this and create a flash message with the `$e->getMessage()` into it.

Is this considered bad architecture ? If yes, how can i do this properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could catch all your application's exceptions in your `Module.php`. When an event is created in your `onBootstrap` method, you can attach a function which will handle the thrown execption.

So you'll have something like this:

```
//file : Module.php

public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $em= $event->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $em->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, [$this, 'handleException']);
    $em->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER_ERROR, [$this, 'handleException']);
}

public function handleException(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $e= $event->getParam('exception');
    $flashMessenger = new FlashMessenger();
    $flashMessenger->setNamespace('error');
    $flashMessenger->addMessage($e->getMessage());

    $event->getViewModel()->setVariable('flashMessages', $flashMessenger->getMessages());
   
}
```

In your views (mostly in `layout.phtml`) :

```
<?php if(isset($flashMessages)) : ?>
<ul class="errors">
    <?php foreach ($flashMessages as $flashMessage) : ?>
    <li><?php echo $flashMessage; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

May be you could also see this intersting [post](http://michaelthessel.com/zf2-flash-messages/)

Comment: HUm, from what i see here, it's what i wanted. I upvote you and wait for tests to accept your answer ! :)

Comment: I created month ago, a listener for flash message, with EVENT_RENDER, i added here your solution of handleException, all work as expected. But is there a way to say : Hey i thrown an exception but i don't want to show you a dedicated page with a flash message only i want to show you the page you were before when the exception was raised.

Comment: If I correctly understood, you want to stay on the same page and just show message that an exception was raised, right? I'm not sure if you can do that with the actual solution. But please post it as new question, because this is a different problem.

Comment: Yes this is it, i want to stay on the same page. Ok i will do this :)

Comment: This is the new question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820777/how-to-show-a-flashmessage-raised-by-an-exception-without-the-error-template

Answer (score 0):

You're basically asking if it's better to put the logic in the action of the controller or handling this controller/application wise.

I'd say in the action is fine, because eventually there may be some cases (now or in the future) where you need to handle the error/exception in a different way in another part of the application

Comment: It is already the case, i want to centralize all my exception's message to show them to my user, decorated with a flash message.