# How to show a flashMessage raised by an exception without the error template

Tags: php, exception, zend-framework2

I have an exception raised in my service.

This exception is handle by a Listener attached by :

```
$this->listeners[] = $events->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER_ERROR, array($this, 'handleException'));
$this->listeners[] = $events->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, array($this, 'handleException'));
```

Handle Exception designed into flashMessage by:

```
public function handleException(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $exception = $event->getParam('exception');
    if ($exception) {
        $flashMessenger = new FlashMessenger();
        $flashMessenger->setNamespace('danger');
        $flashMessenger->addMessage($exception->getMessage());

        $event->getViewModel()->setVariable('flashMessages', $flashMessenger->getMessages());
    }
}
```

Now, with this code how can i stay to the same page where the exception was raised. I can't show the error/template on each exception, i have to keep my users on the same page for confort.

This question is the following part of this one :

[Handle Exception in ZF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29798332/handle-all-exceptions-thrown-put-them-into-flashmessage-with-zf2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for a specific error; if it is found you can then redirect back to the same page to display the flash message.

ZF2 currently does this with the `Zend\Mvc\View\Http\RouteNotFoundStrategy`, for 404 errors and `Zend\Mvc\View\Http\ExceptionStrategy` for generic exceptions; so you will need to attach your event's with a *higher* priority (than `1`) so they are executed first.

You should change the controller code (from your original question) to add the exception to the MVC event and manually trigger the dispatch error.

**Edit** If you wish to cut down the code, [the dispatch listener does handle exceptions from the controller by triggering the `MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR` for you](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/DispatchListener.php#L95). I've not tested this however you *should* be able to listen for a custom exception, again providing you have a event priority higher that `1`.

```
public function fooAction()
{
    try {
        throw new \Exception('A error occurred');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {

        // Throw a custom exception
        throw new MyCustomException('Some error');
    }
}
```

Your event listener can now check for this and handle the redirection.

```
public function handleException(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $event)
{
    $error = $event->getError();
    $exception = $event->getParam('exception');

    if (! $error || ! $exception instanceof MyCustomException) {
       return;
    }

    $serviceManager = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $controllerPluginManager = $serviceManager->get('ControllerPluginManager');

    $flashMessenger = $controllerPluginManager->get('FlashMessenger');

    $flashMessenger->setNamespace('danger');
    $flashMessenger->addMessage($exception->getMessage());

    return $controllerPluginManager->get('redirect')->refresh();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it's really nice ; I just can't do that on each action wich raise an exception, it's too heavy, and a lot of duplicated code. Do you have an idea to make this more efficient ?

Comment: @Hooli I've updated, although I've in no way tested this so I'll be interested if it works OK.

Comment: Ok, i'll give you a feedback on this, promis.

Comment: So the feedback, this code do the trick, but i don't want to create a custom Exception yet, so i tried to do so with \Exception instead, and i have redirection loop, during development for each error i get. But if we consider this as a minor thing, it works.